# Appium Date Picker Scroll android

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, automator

Hey Guys I am new to Appium Automation testing... I need to work on automating the android default OS Date picker dialog as per the below image. Can some one help me on this?[Date picker dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT4Py.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
Just Use the below code

First open your date picker and use the sample code..


public static String datePicker_ui_id = "android:id/datePicker";

public static String pickers_ui_id = "android:id/pickers";

public static String NumberPicker_ui_id = "//android.widget.NumberPicker";

public static String numberpicker_input_ui_id = "android:id/numberpicker_input";

public static String startDate = "10";

public static String EndDate = "20";

public static String startMonth = "Jun";

public static String Year = "2017";

public static String aler_dialog_cancel_ui_id = "//android.widget.Button[@resource-id='android:id/button2']";

public static String aler_dialog_ok_ui_id = "//android.widget.Button[@resource-id='android:id/button1']";

driver.findElement(By.id(datePicker_ui_id)).findElement(By.id(pickers_ui_id)).findElement(By.xpath(NumberPicker_ui_id+"[1]")).findElement(By.id(numberpicker_input_ui_id)).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id(datePicker_ui_id)).findElement(By.id(pickers_ui_id)).findElement(By.xpath(NumberPicker_ui_id+"[1]")).findElement(By.id(numberpicker_input_ui_id)).sendKeys(startDate);
driver.findElement(By.id(datePicker_ui_id)).findElement(By.id(pickers_ui_id)).findElement(By.xpath(NumberPicker_ui_id+"[2]")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id(datePicker_ui_id)).findElement(By.id(pickers_ui_id)).findElement(By.xpath(NumberPicker_ui_id+"[2]")).findElement(By.id(numberpicker_input_ui_id)).sendKeys(startMonth);
driver.findElement(By.id(datePicker_ui_id)).findElement(By.id(pickers_ui_id)).findElement(By.xpath(NumberPicker_ui_id+"[3]")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id(datePicker_ui_id)).findElement(By.id(pickers_ui_id)).findElement(By.xpath(NumberPicker_ui_id+"[3]")).findElement(By.id(numberpicker_input_ui_id)).sendKeys(Year);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(aler_dialog_ok_ui_id)).click();
```

Comment: @Mohan If you still found any difficulty please let me know i am more than happy to help you..

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you have to automate a scroll action from left-to-right or right-to-left.

This is an example of how to scroll from right-to-left:

```
    new TouchAction(wd)
            .press(900, 800)
            .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
            .moveTo(900, 200)
            .release()
            .perform();
```

You can use appium desktop in order to get the proper coordinates, since the resolution of your device matters.